# Overwriting default Code Snippets

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, code-snippets

I have been making several improvements on code snippets that are typically built into VS2010. Is there any way to either "prefer" certain snippet directories over others, or to overwrite the defaults without manually removing the references from the Code Snippets window? I would like to keep the same shortcuts.

This is mostly nit-picking, since I could remove the .snippet files manually, or remove the folder references, but I'm wondering if there is an easier way, incase I end up replacing a large amount of the default snippets yet still want to keep others.

There are two issues that come up when having similar shortcuts on code snippets.

1. For some snippets, such as `propdp`, you will be prompted that there are multiple snippets, and be asked to choose which one is appropriate.
2. For other snippets, such as `ctor`, it just uses the default snippet and pretends my own doesn't exist. Browsing the snippets using Ctrl+K,Ctrl+X clearly shows the snippet works, and the shortcut is correct.

The second issue here is a larger concern than the first.

**Edit:** Further experimentation shows that `ctor` in particular uses the default snippet no matter what. I haven't tried overwriting the code in the original snippet file, but removing the reference to Visual C# snippets folder still uses the default and ignores my replacement.

**Edit 2:** Even replacing the original snippet, `ctor` uses the default and ignores the .snippet file. This is after restarting Visual Studio as well. Now I have no idea where it's even retrieving this code snippet from. As a test, you can rename the snippet `ctors` and it will display properly. `ctor` is no longer a suggestion at this point. If you rename it back to `ctor`, it will once again display the default snippet. Either this snippet is cached somewhere, or it's built in to VS2010.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried simply overwriting the original files, replacing the snippet with your own?

They're located here: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC#\Snippets\1033\Visual C#

Comment: I was just trying to create a more general-purpose solution. The problems I see with this is it requires finding the location of each snippet (for example, propdp is located in NetFX30, not Visual C#), requires administrator access to overwrite the files, and becomes a per-snippet process to install. I'm currently just dropping all my snippets in Dropbox and adding the folder reference in VS2010.

Comment: Now, as I've stated above, I've learned that replacing the snippet for `ctor` ends up doing nothing. I have no idea where it's even retrieving this snippet from, perhaps its built-in to VS2010 and I can't override it.

Comment: Maybe. I've only tried to overwrite existing snippets, and make brand new ones.

Answer (score 0):

On my system, the C# snippets are stored in two places at least:

- C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC#\Snippets\1033\Visual C#
- C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\VC#\Snippets\1033\Visual C#

I think you're right that Microsoft's snippets always "win" when you have snippets in other directories, so to use customized snippets, you end up having to overwrite the originals. But every couple of weeks when an update to Visual Studio is released, the update will obliterate your versions in favor of MS's. (Why did they bother to expose this functionality if they're going to disrespectfully ignore or obliterate your customizations?)

I ended up just writing a program that starts running at login time to watch these two directories. When something changes in one of them, it compares the snippets there to ones I have stored in a "snippet override" directory, and if they aren't the same, it restores my versions of the snippets.

Answer (score -1):

Have you looked at the plug-in for Code Barrel? It has revision support, tagging, etc... Looks like that may be what you need. ~shrug~ it is free, so is the plugin, go to codebarrel.com to get it.

Comment: domain doesn't exist.

Comment: Code Barrel is no longer relevant, as the company was purchased by Atlassian. This would be better suited as a comment on the original question, anyway. And please change your icon.